# Mysql group_concat with sums also inside

Tags: mysql

I have a table of different attributes I want to sum, and then group concatenate them into a JSON string to make it easier to send over network. Here's a simplified table:

```
t1
type    amount
'atr1'  10
'atr2'  10
'atr1'  17
'atr3'  20
'atr3'  4
```

I tried something like

```
select concat('{', 
    group_concat(
        (select concat('"', type, '":', sum(amount)) from t1 group by type)
    ),
'}')
```

but failed.

I want to end up with `'{"atr1":27,"atr2":10,"atr3":24}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT CONCAT('{', GROUP_CONCAT(c1), '}') FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT('"', type, '":', SUM(amount)) c1 FROM t1 GROUP BY type
  ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
select 
    group_concat(concat('"', type, '":', TheSum))
FROM
    (
    SELECT SUM(amount) AS TheSum,type
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY type
    ) T
```